# Four fundamental subspaces. Orthogonality

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am having trouble understanding how to implement the four fundamental subspaces. I have read about the subject and understand the meaning but do not understand how to implement it when asked in a question. Can someone help me better grasp this.

An example question would be:

For each Matrix, accurately sketch the four fundamental subspaces on two R^2 plots so that the orthogonal pairs of subspaces are plotted together. This is the grid picture:

```
  |1 2|      |1 0|
A=|3 6|    B=|3 0|
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

OK, so start by finding the four fundamental subspaces.  What are they?

Comment: So Im looking for the column space, null space, row space and left nullspace correct?

Comment: Yes.  So, let's start with the column space.  What is it for $A$?

Comment: Would the new matrix be rows [1 0] and [0 0]?

Comment: So we get C(A) = 1, C(A^T) = 1, Nullspace = x2[01], left Null = 1

Comment: Column space is by definition the linear span of the columns.  In the case of $A$, the second column is $2$ times the first, so the column space is the span of $\pmatrix{1\cr 3\cr}$.